# In TeeChart for HTML5, how to darken the gradient fill on a pie chart?

Tags: html, teechart

I'm evaluating TeeChart for a project, and the colors seem washed out.  Note the difference between the dark, bold colors of the legend and the darkest section of the pie chart itself.  I'm including my code below.  I like the look of the gradient fill, but how can I get it to darken closer to the center of the pie and fully darken around the edges?

[image]

```
function pie_draw(arChartValues, arChartLabels) {
    chart1=new Tee.Chart("pie_canvas");
    pieSeries=new Tee.Pie(arChartValues);
    pieSeries.data.labels=arChartLabels;
    chart1.addSeries(pieSeries);
    chart1.panel.format.gradient.colors=['white','#f0f9ff'];        
    chart1.panel.format.stroke.size=2;
    chart1.title.text="Learning Progress";
    chart1.title.format.font.fill = '#314d65';
    chart1.draw();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out enough to move on.  After some experimentation, I ended up adding the following line.

```
pieSeries.format.gradient.stops=[0,0.15];
```